# Passing arguments to AutoIt program using Python

Tags: python, autoit

Here is the AutoIt code to upload a file every time when it gets executed in Python. I replaced the file path to $CmdLine[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5L6v.png) so that I can pass a new file path every time.

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1", "$CmdLine[1]")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

How can I pass a new file path using Python? I use

```
os.startfile('path to the autoit.exe file')
```

I read that there is a way to pass such argument in java as follows,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(r"path to autoit.exe file"+""+"file path to be uploaded");
```

When I tried to execute this cmd using command line it doesn't pass the desired arguement.

```
AutoIt3.exe C:\Users\Downloads\file_upload.exe C:\Users\Downloads\1.png
```

[image]

It types the same $CmdLine[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5L6v.png) argument in the text field as follows.
[image]

Is there any other way that I can pass a new file name as an argument in python's for loop so that It will upload multiple files?

Here is the code for adding images to Google slides website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import os
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\praba\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
#options.add_argument("--profile-directory='Profile 1'")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver',options=options)
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/presentation/u/0/create?usp=slides_web")
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('insertImageMenuButton')
time.sleep(5)
elem.click()
time.sleep(5)
el1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[35]/div[1]/div/span')))
el1.click()
time.sleep(3)
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\praba\Downloads\file_open.exe")
```

Comment: Try using the Subprocess library from within Python.
That will allow you to start the app as shell (no CMD window will popup) and read the exit code.
More info. at:
https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-python/

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after a lot of struggle. The problem was the double quotes on the $CmdLine[1] parameter.

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

So removing the double-quotes and calling the exe file from the command line opens the desired file.

```
os.system('commandline to execute autoit program with the uploading file path')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe add a little more context?  How would you be retrieving the new file path?  I will try to answer based on the information you've provided.

If it's in an automated fashion, you should in theory be able to just call that `ControlSetText` with the new path (string) you've retrieved.

If you need to input it manually, you can call something like `input('Please enter the new file location. \n')` and store that in a variable you then pass into the `ControlSetText`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my intended python code to upload a file to the google slide.

Comment: I want to upload more than one image from a folder. So I want to create a for loop and pass the file path as an argument so that the Autoit program will pick up a new file every time it gets executed.

Comment: Ok, so the 'user-data-dir' is the directory you're passing in as an argument, and that you wanted to iterate over? Subsequently, going through & uploading each file within that directory?

Comment: Yes. The directory doesn't matter. When I click the "upload image from computer" option in Google slides, It prompts the "open" window to select a file. I want to add my desired file path to that window and want to add multiple images one by one.